# Red5 Pro: Unexpected response code: 400 & WebSocketException - Handshake failed

Tags: websocket, streaming, webrtc, red5, red5pro

I set [Red5 Pro server](https://www.red5pro.com/docs/server/setup/) on developer licence locally, then I ran [red5pro/streaming-android](https://github.com/red5pro/streaming-android) application (I ran app from Android Studio). I saw on `http://localhost:5080/live/subscribe.jsp` my stream from application, and when I clicked `http://[my IP]/live/viewer.jsp?host=192.168.1.103&stream=Radek[Stream name in Android app]` to subscribe it opens, but in log on page I saw:

> [Red5ProSubscriber] Connect.Failure.

And in Chrome Developer Tools:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://[my IP]:8081/live?id=subscriber-2bb5' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

In `cmd` I saw:

> org.red5.net.websocket.codec.WebSocketDecoder - Handshake failed
>   org.red5.net.websocket.WebSocketException - Handshake failed, path not enabled.

Here is log from `cmd`:
[image: WebSocketException - Handshake failed, path not enable]

I did not modify anything in server code. Should I manually enable `WebSocket` or `WebRTC` somewhere? I didn't find anything about it in [Red5 Pro WebRTC](https://www.red5pro.com/docs/server/webrtc/). I don't think something is wrong with my PC - it happens before also in my workplace. What is weird - if I provide key I can connect with API, for example I can list streams with Postman. I will be grateful to you for taking the time, thank you in advance for help.

P.S. I also created a post in [Red5Pro community](https://red5pro.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000042708-Unexpected-response-code-400-WebSocketException-Handshake-failed). What is really weird, it works on Windows 10 when I run `.bat`, but not when I run it with administrator privileges. It also won't work for debug version, and it won't work for any version on Windows 7 in my work (the same error as described here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was problem with missing libraries, I didn't solve it on Windows 7, but on our local development server on [Linux we had to install missing software dependencies](https://www.red5pro.com/docs/server/ubuntuinstall/):

> $ apt-get install libva1
>
> $ apt-get install libva-drm1
>
> $ apt-get install libva-x11-1
>
> $ apt-get install libvdpau1

Comment: It says  , They are all newest version

Comment: On windows 7, 8, 10; you must use x64; there is not 32 bit support.